# Creating intellisense type control in JavaScript and HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm about to embark in creating a Jquery plugin that will provide a type ahead lookup in a similar way to how it's presented in visual studio.

Whilst I'm familiar to autocomplete and other similar type ahead plugins I want to make it so that the pop up is positioned under the word that's being typed in a text area.

Is there a way to get the current x and y of the caret within a text box?

Thanks

Sam

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5149683/how-to-get-selected-text-caret-position-of-an-input-that-doesnt-have-focus

Comment: Thanks but I believe that's referring to the position of the caret within the character string, not screen position relative to window/element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a complex solution which involves overlaying the input with a canvas element and measuring the text in that (or just having a hidden canvas element) - but this I don't think will work in older IE.

You can measure the width of the text by adding up the characters and their relative width (with a known width mono font). Then just grabbing the input's top/left and adding the charWidth * num of chars prior to the word (including whitespace) should give you an somewhat accurate 'top/left' of the end (or beginning if you make it this way) of the word.

If you need a coded example let me know and I can whip up something suitable. However this (imo) would be the easiest way to do this (mono font + calculating widths + input offsets)

Comment: Curious...will this work in a textarea where the lines have wrapped?

Comment: Possibly... you can read some of the docs on ranges and how to determine new lines.. or do like a lot of Wysiwyg and offer a iframe + off screen input or contenteditable div maybe?

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, From what I can find out its not really possible. I've learnt a lot about range js helpers like rangy so that's been useful. Maybe best solution would be fixed height and width fonts. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve using selection and range API's. But there are lot of differences with API's between IE and Non-IE. Please look into msdn and mdn for selection and range API's.