# Get current cursor position in a textbox

Tags: javascript, firefox, textbox, text-cursor

I need a code to find **current position of cursor in a textbox/textarea**. It should work with chrome and firefox. Following is the code which I am using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function textbox()
      {
        document.getElementById('Javascript_example').value = document.activeElement.id;
        var ctl = document.getElementById('Javascript_example');
        alert(ctl);

        var startPos = ctl.selectionStart;
        alert(startPos);
        var endPos = ctl.selectionEnd;
        alert(endPos);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <input id="Javascript_example" name="one" type="text" value="Javascript_example" onclick="textbox()">

  </body>
</html>
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/eR4qc/7/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get caret position in textarea?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263743/how-to-get-caret-position-in-textarea)

Comment: @rakhee he wants the cursor position, not the textbox's x and y co-ordinates on the page. Helps to read the whole question buddy ;)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

It looks OK apart from the space in your ID attribute, which is not valid, and the fact that you're replacing the value of your input before checking the selection.

```js
function textbox()
{
        var ctl = document.getElementById('Javascript_example');
        var startPos = ctl.selectionStart;
        var endPos = ctl.selectionEnd;
        alert(startPos + ", " + endPos);
}
```

```html
<input id="Javascript_example" name="one" type="text" value="Javascript example" onclick="textbox()">
```

Also, if you're supporting IE <= 8 you need to be aware that those browsers do not support `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd`.

Comment: Really, you are kidding me. I removed the document.getElementById('Javascript_example').value = document.activeElement.id; line from my code. And it works. Thank you anyway. You have shown me the right way :)

Answer (score 6):

Here's one possible method.

```
function isMouseInBox(e) {
  var textbox = document.getElementById('textbox');

  // Box position & sizes
  var boxX = textbox.offsetLeft;
  var boxY = textbox.offsetTop;
  var boxWidth = textbox.offsetWidth;
  var boxHeight = textbox.offsetHeight;

  // Mouse position comes from the 'mousemove' event
  var mouseX = e.pageX;
  var mouseY = e.pageY;
  if(mouseX>=boxX && mouseX<=boxX+boxWidth) {
    if(mouseY>=boxY && mouseY<=boxY+boxHeight){
       // Mouse is in the box
       return true;
    }
  }
}

document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){
    isMouseInBox(e);
})
```

Comment: No. I want to get the position. Let say, if I click on JavaScript and insertion point/carret is after Java , then it should return 4

Comment: Ah I completely misunderstood, I interpreted "cursor" as meaning the mouse cursor. See this maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5149683/how-to-get-selected-text-caret-position-of-an-input-that-doesnt-have-focus

Comment: English, so many ways to interpret something as simple as cursor ;)