# Replacing one specific word in the textarea

Tags: javascript, hashtag

I have created a hashtag and user mention input, so that when you type an '@' it displays a list of users you may know.

[image]

To this point, everything is Okey, But when I click on a user a href tag :

```
    <a href="javascript:void(0);">
       <span style="background:url('/uploads/user_00010/thumbs/32x32_d30302e9-07d7-8fd7-dba0-1a217c9c5534.jpg') no-repeat" class="tny_avatar"></span>
<span class="username">Sara</span>                
    <span style="height:0px;display:block;" class="clr"></span>
</a>
```

I want to take its username, and put it directly in the right place in the textarea...

**What I did:**

I take the current word in the textarea (currentWord = 'sa' in the previous screenshot)... and replace this current word with the word in the username span from the list.

The problem with this solution is that, if the substring "sa" exists in another word in the textarea, it will replace it too.

This is my js code :

```
$('.suggest ul li a').live('click', function () {
    var text = $('.quote textarea').val();

    var newVal = $(this).find('.username').html();

    text = text.replace(lastWord, '@' + newVal);

    $('.advText').val(text);

    $('.advText').trigger('keyup');

    $('.tglst').hide();

});
```

lastWord is the current word, where the blanking cursor is pointing; It's a global js variable.

`trigger('keyup')` , is just triggering some functions creating a div containing the hashtags and mentions in different color (blue). That's all it's about.

`$('.tglst').hide();`   is hiding the dropdown.

Does anyone know how to replace the current word only?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you replace only the last occurence of the given string; that is, the one you're currently typing? (I'm aware of the tradeoff that it poses) You could use `lastIndexOf` or the `/[whatever]$/` RegEx or something like these.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about it, the tradeoff (maybe you know it)...is that if the user changes the cursor position to type a mention elsewhere in the textarea... the dropdown will take only the last occurence into account ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, you could replace the very last word, that is most probably the one you're currently typing.

Or you can **[take a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16105482/get-current-cursor-position-in-a-texbox)** and see how to get the current cursor position. You'll have the exact word to replace afterwards.

Comment: Yes, fortunately.,I already have the current cursor position...Since I used it in the keyup when typing the word... I will make it global and figure out how to use it in this case..
Thanks that's the solution. I will give it a try.

Comment: @SmootQ I think there should be another way around than using globals. They're the root of evil :) Moreover, as keyup should be responsible for triggering the whole thing, you can just pass the data to a lower level function as an argument. (Not sure why it is necessary to trigger an additional keyup though)

Comment: Yes, I will create a function for that,thank you so much :) Your solution is working ... thnx again