# Get Cursor position in Edittable span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have editable span i want to add text on cursor position on button click.
This span have multi line value and html tag.

```
[Link](http://jsfiddle.net/8txz9sjs/)
```

Comment: Possibly related to this -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16105482/get-current-cursor-position-in-a-texbox

Answer (score 1):

Use **[Range.insertNode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/insertNode)**:

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  var range= getSelection().getRangeAt(0),
      text= document.createTextNode('NEW TEXT');
  range.insertNode(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='div_template' contenteditable="true">
    asdf asfd asd
 asdf 
    asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf<br/>
adf asfd asdf  sdafasdf
 asdf asdf asd    
</div>
<button>Set Text</button>
```