# JavaScript - Determine whether the cursor is a the beginning of the text contained in a container, ignoring whitespace

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to determine whether the cursor is at the beginning of a container (where contenteditable is true), ignoring whitespace or HTML elements that comes first.  For instance:

```
<div class="layout-container" contenteditable="true">
    <div class="slice-content">
        <p>       Hello World</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="layout-container" contenteditable="true">
    <div class="slice-content">
        <p>Hello World</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="layout-container" contenteditable="true">
    <div class="slice-content">
        <p>  <span style="font-weight: normal;">Hello</span> World</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Regardless of which ones of these is used to create the following:
[image]

**I would still want it to return 0.**

Currently, I am using the following:

```
window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).startOffset;
```

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16105482/get-current-cursor-position-in-a-textbox