# How to write at cursor position into input box with a button in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, button, input, cursor

I have a button that when clicked writes a text to a specific input box, but I have many input boxes and I would like to set it to write anywhere my cursor is at the moment, or whichever input box is selected. How can I do this?

Comment: Google for *js get input with focus*, then *js get input cursor position* and finaly *js add char to the middle of string*. I guarantee you these keywords will lead you to the right stackoverflow questions.

Comment: Probable this link will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16105482/get-current-cursor-position-in-a-textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Idea to solve this problem is

1. when user click a input box save element reference to a variable
   including position with help of this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16105482/get-current-cursor-position-in-a-textbox)

   ```
   var elInfo = {
      el : object, // element reference
      pos: 0 // current position
   };
   ```
2. when user click that button retrieve information from the variable and append your text to the element.