# Best way to adjust letter spacing every 3 chars in Ionic/Angular input box

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework

I'd like users to enter a code and to assist them in transcribing it I'd hope to increase the spacing between every 3rd character they type. I've seen this nicely done for credit cards having 4 character spacing. This will be for an Ionic app so the simple input box coud be replaced with a customised Ionic control.

What methods have you used for this and what works best? 
Open to Angular/Ionic code samples or a related web site tutorial.
Pure CSS would be nice.

Comment: Is the code alphanumeric input?

Comment: I may use it for either number or non-numeric input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an other version, without jquery, works with alphanumerical and takes a configurable separator:

**Typescript:**

```
GROUP_SEPARATOR=" ";
...... 
format(valString) {
    if (!valString) {
        return '';
    }
    let val = valString.toString();
    const parts = val.replace(/ /g, '');
    return parts.replace(/\B(?=(?:\w{3})+(?!\w))/g, this.GROUP_SEPARATOR) 
};
```

**HTML**

```
<input [(ngModel)]="input"  
style="border:1px solid black" #myBudget="ngModel" (input)="input = format(input)">
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-putzbl?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Thanks for the working demo. Current code has a bug that puts a space after the 2nd char whenever you've entered 3n + 1 chars.  

- Example: "abcd" => "a bcd"

Comment: It meant to be like that, but now, I think you would prefer "abc d" ?

Comment: This one should be what you meant: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kp2j5v?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: Or just use `format(val) { return val.replace(/([^ ][^ ][^ ]) */g, "\$1 ").trim(); }`

Comment: I already tested it, but when you edit the input it breaks :(

Comment: Worked for me.  I tested it with your demo app code.  What was the error you saw?

Comment: No error, just after entering, if I come back and enter a new character, then the formatting is broken, ( abc def g -> I insert h between b and c, it makes abh c def g).

Comment: Right ... So we just need to strip out any existing spaces before inserting them back: `format(val) { return val.replace(/ +/g, "").replace(/([^ ][^ ][^ ])/g, "\$1 ").trim();  }

Answer (score 1):

You can add space on keyup event.

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/VijayBaskaran88/e4g2h8ys/1/)

```
$('#input').on('keyup', function(e){
    var val = $(this).val();
    var newval = '';
    val = val.replace(/\s/g, '');
    for(var i=0; i < val.length; i++) {
        if(i%3 == 0 && i > 0) newval = newval.concat(' ');
        newval = newval.concat(val[i]);
    }
    $(this).val(newval);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a simpler method based on Vija's method ... Basically we match 3 non-space chars and we remove any previously added space chars. This is needed to allow the user to update or erase any chars in the text box.

A final solution may also need to adjust the [position of the cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16105482/get-current-cursor-position-in-a-textbox) based on where it was prior to performing the replace.

```
$('#input').on('keyup', function(e){
  var val = $(this).val();
  var newval = val.replace(/([^ ][^ ][^ ]) */g, "\$1 ").trim();
  $(this).val(newval);
})
```