# How can I work out whether the cursor in a textarea is in the first or last line, using JS or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

Please note the difference of a line wrap and a line break.
Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <body>
            <form action="/action_page.php">
                <textarea rows="2" cols="20" name="usrtxt" wrap="soft">
                    I'am only one line without line breaks. Look joe I don't break but I wrap.
                </textarea>
                <input type="submit">
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/b5dtjvbo/1/

I want to know if the cursor is in the first or last line. Like at the top or bottom of the textarea.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get current cursor position in a textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16105482/get-current-cursor-position-in-a-textbox)

Comment: No @lazzy_ms ! It's not! You just need to read the headline.

Comment: see the accepted answer, there.

Comment: Take a look at my headline. Much more complex. Please just skip this one.

Answer (score 2):

Is the only solution to do pixel measuring of the textarea and than count how much letters would fit in those pixel-width ??

Comment: The problem with this is word-wrapping, which you also need to account for. Not every line will break at the same number of characters.

Answer (score 1):

you can do similar to this with this you can get position of mouse

```js
var indicator = document.getElementById("indicator");
var textarea = document.getElementById("textarea");
     
     setInterval(function() { 
     indicator.value = caret(textarea);
     }, 100);
  
    
    function caret(node) {
    if(node.selectionStart) return node.selectionStart;
     else if(!document.selection) return 0;
     var c  = "\001";
     var sel = document.selection.createRange();
     var dul = sel.duplicate();
     var len = 0;
     dul.moveToElementText(node);
     sel.text = c;
     len  = (dul.text.indexOf(c));
     sel.moveStart('character',-1);
     sel.text = "";
     return len;
    }
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea" style="width:80%;height:100px;">
I'am only one line without line breaks. Look joe I don't break but I wrap.
</textarea><br>
<input type="text" id="indicator" style="width:25px;">
```

Comment: I need more than mouse position. Thank you

Comment: more ?? If you are asking about adding more lines and getting position just try it will work. this just example,what you want to do after getting Position ?

Comment: Read the title @v8

Comment: this possibly will go in chat,You can do one thing provide fixed size Text are and then use above code to know position, Dont know what is your requirement but you can do this. Best example is STACK OVERFLOW's  Comment section it allows you to enter limited characters :)

Comment: thanks, but I guess it's not possible because I cant limit the text and I it's supposed to work in every possible textarea. Like with scrollbar, without, every size. 
My req is to be able to jump via predefined keyboard shortcuts out of the textarea. When in first line jump dirctly out when pressin arrow up for example

Comment: lets have chat will help you if you want,we can move this to chat session on Stack ,if you want?

Comment: I don't have enough reputation points to enter the chat as it seems

Answer (score 0):

Pls refer following snippet,

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script>
        function f1(el) {
        var val = el.value;
        var position=val.slice(0,el.selectionStart).length;
        //  alert(position)
        if(parseInt(position)>=0 && parseInt(position)<=18)
          alert("cursor is on top line")
        else if(parseInt(position)>=19 && parseInt(position)<=39)
          alert("cursor is on middle line")
        else
          alert("cursor is on last line")


    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

<textarea rows="2" cols="20" id='t1' name="usrtxt" wrap="soft" onclick="f1(document.getElementById('t1'))">
I'am only one line without line breaks. Look joe I don't break but I wrap.
</textarea>


</body>
    </html>
```

---

My edited answer ........

I am try to get position dynamically after adding more lines

For that purpose I refer https://github.com/component/textarea-caret-position 
this url, and modify original source code

Please refer following jsfiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/6u1gwfeh/1/

hope this meet your requirement !!

Comment: there is bug in this code just try to add more line and run you will find it ,even if you add more lines it gives alert("cursor is on last line")

Comment: @v8 sagar if you add more line then you also need to update f1 function accordingly then it will work.

Comment: this not feasible solution Bhau hech sangtoy me

Comment: @Miso Please see my edited answer hope this will helpful to you !!

Comment: @AbhijeetKale If I'm not wrong, that's just for finding the cursor position. I need more.