# I need to identify exact location of keypress inside html text area and input text field

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I want to implement a completion field inside my textarea.
Everytime a user types $ a drop down below the char location should appear and display a selection of placeholder/text which if clicked should insert text on the current cursor position.

At the moment I have implemented an event handler which catches keypress events and creates in the parent of the textarea a modal div with that text.

My only problem is I can't figure out how to correctly position my modal dlg, because I can't find any position information.

How do i do the math to end up at the correct character/key location?
What attributes can I use for calculation?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29709/how-do-i-get-the-x-y-pixel-coordinates-of-the-caret-in-text-boxes

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16105482/get-current-cursor-position-in-a-textbox