# Javascript Chrome Extention get caret coordinates

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, getcaretpos

I just started with a new chrome extension however I couldn't find how to get the exact caret (text cursor) position in JavaScript

code

```
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function (command) {
    console.log('Command:', command);
    if (command == "OpenRightclick-menu") {
        // Get coordinates
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get access to current cursor position from your content script.

If you have an DOM node of element, you can check [selectionStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Property/selectionStart) and [selectionEnd](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Property/selectionEnd) properties.

If you don't have DOM node - you can check answer on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5149683/how-to-get-selected-text-caret-position-of-an-input-that-doesnt-have-focus).